# mysqli_set_charset does not set charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

$db is link to the db made by mysqli_connect(...);

```
mysqli_set_charset($db,"UTF-8");
die(mysqli_character_set_name($db)); //returns (string) "latin1";
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not recognize "UTF-8". Use "utf8".

```
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
```

You can get a list of the spellings that MySQL recognizes:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS
WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME LIKE 'utf%';
```